# Inputting first array something goes wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm new at C++ and just learned creating random numbers so I created a Lottery game that have 6 generated random numbers range 1 to 49 and the user will guess it but it seems to have an issue [see the output below]

[image: ]].

when I input the first array that array output it first before the word ("Your numbers are: )

this is my code by the way

```
 /*int lottoNumbers[6];
  int myLotto[6];
  int ok=1;
  int money=100;
  srand(time(0));
    */
  for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
  {
      int n=1+(rand()%49);
      lottoNumbers[j]=n;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
      for (int j=i+1; j<6; j++)
        {
            if (lottoNumbers[i] == lottoNumbers[j])
            {
                lottoNumbers[j]=(rand()%49+2)/2;
            }
        }
  }
  cout<<"Input your Lucky Numbers: "<<endl;
  for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
  {
      cin>>myLotto[j];
  }
  cout<<endl;
  for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
  {
      for (int j=i+1; j<=6; j++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i]==myLotto[j])
          {
              ok=2;
          }
      }
  }
  for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
  {
      if (myLotto[i]>49 || myLotto[i]<1 || ok==2)
      {
          cout<<"\nInappropriate. Lost for lottery";
          ok=0;
          break;
      }
  }
  if (ok==1)
  {
      for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
      {
          if (i==1)
          {
              cout<<"\nYour numbers are: "<<endl;
          }
          if (myLotto[i]<=49 && myLotto[i]>=1)
          {
              cout<<myLotto[i]<<" ";
          }
      }
  }
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"\nWinning number this time: "<<endl;
  for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
      cout<<lottoNumbers[i]<<" ";
  }
  int nr=0;
  for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
  {
      for (int j=1; j<=6; j++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i]==lottoNumbers[j])
          {
              nr++;
          }
      }
  }
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;

  int jk=0;

  if (jk==0)
  {
      cout<<"You hit "<<nr<<" numbers."<<endl;
      cout<<"You have "<<(nr*100)/6<<"% chances to win."<<endl;
  }else
  {
      cout<<"You GOT THE JACKPOT";
  }
 /* if (nr==1 || nr==2 )
  {
      money = money + 20;
  }
  if (nr==3)
  {
      money = money + 50;
  }
  if (nr==4)
  {
      money = money + 100;
  }
  if (nr==5)
  {
      money = money + 10000;
  }
  if (nr==6)
  {
      money = money + 100000;
  }
  if (nr==0)
  {
      money= money -10;
  }
  cout<<"Your Money: "<<money<<endl;
*/
  cout<<endl;
```

and is there a method to make it simplier

Comment: Your loop starts from zero. At index 1 you print the text. It functions as written. Don’t put it inside the loop since it doesn’t belong there.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `i == 1` on the *second* time around your printing loop, so obviously `"Your numbers are"` gets printed after the first number. I guess that somehow you forgot that your loop starts with `i == 0`.

It's an easy fix, just change this

```
 if (ok==1)
  {
      for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
      {
          if (i==1)
          {
              cout<<"\nYour numbers are: "<<endl;
          }
          if (myLotto[i]<=49 && myLotto[i]>=1)
          {
              cout<<myLotto[i]<<" ";
          }
      }
  }
```

to this

```
 if (ok==1)
  {
      cout<<"\nYour numbers are: "<<endl;
      for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i]<=49 && myLotto[i]>=1)
          {
              cout<<myLotto[i]<<" ";
          }
      }
  }
```

You make similar mistakes in several places in your code, for instance this

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
  {
      for (int j=i+1; j<=6; j++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i]==myLotto[j])
          {
              ok=2;
          }
      }
  }
```

should be this

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
      for (int j=i+1; j<6; j++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i]==myLotto[j])
          {
              ok=2;
          }
      }
  }
```

Remember that arrays start at zero in C++, so you for loops should as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I am not dealing with duplication of neither generated random numbers nor duplicate input.

I would do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::array<int, 6> winningNumbers;

    //generate random numbers
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 50);
    for(auto& i : winningNumbers){
        i = distribution(generator);
    }

    std::array<int, 6> inputNumbers;

    std::cout << "Input your lucky numbers:\n";
    for(auto& i : inputNumbers)
        std::cin >> i;

    std::cout << "\nYour numbers are: ";

    for(const auto& i : inputNumbers)
        std::cout << i << "\n";

    std::cout << "Winning Numbers this time:\n";
    for(const auto& i : winningNumbers){
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }

    short numbersHit = 0;

    for(const auto& i : winningNumbers){
        if(std::find(inputNumbers.begin(), inputNumbers.end(), i) != inputNumbers.end())
            ++numbersHit;

    }

    std::cout << "You hit " << numbersHit << "\n";
}
```